# R: Data Frame launching manually works well, in shiny is incomplete

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny

I webscraped 2 tables (A and B). Then I merge them by rows (rbind). When I launch it, everything is ok. When I wanna use it in shiny app there is something wrong. Below structure of tables and what shiny shows. Any suggestion? Where could be the problem? Unfortunatelly, I can not show the code, because this is for my thesis. I would be very grateful for your help.

As you can see the problem is with third column. B table has all rows with NA. After merge, all data from A table has also NA.

In shiny table is showed by renderTable.

[Structure of tables A and B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gw9el.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no answer for your question, but I would like to write something and there is not enough space for this in comment section, so I will write this as answer and eventually delete later. So - I rather believe that there is something wrong with your code which you use inside shiny and would like to check this with your help. I assume you need some help with debugging, so I will post a code below:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  my_df <- reactive({
    data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3),
               b = c(4, 5, 6))
  })
  
  output$table <- renderTable({
    my_df()
    browser()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

In the code above I have made one output (table output) and - on the server side in reactive - I'm creating `data.frame`. Then I use this reactive function inside my output (`output$plot`). However, the last line inside `output$plot` is function `browser()` which is used for debugging. You can try my code in your console and see that when you run shiny app, it immediately moving back to console (but this is "dubugging state", so console looks a little different, for example there is a button "stop" with red square which can be use to close debugging state). Please run my shiny app and when you will be back in the console, in the debugging state, type `my_df()` to see the `data.frame` object. Could you please do the same with your shiny app? I mean, could you use `browser()` function on the last line in your `renderTable`? And come back and tell if the last column contains only `NA` or not when displayed in the console? If not, then I would say that you are doing something different in Shiny than manually with your tables.